# ios_base::ate and tellp()

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{ 
    const char* fileName = "out1"; 
    std::ofstream fs1(fileName); 
    fs1 << "AAAAAAAAAAA\n"; 
    std::cout << fs1.tellp() << std::endl; 
    fs1.close(); 

    std::ofstream fs2(fileName, std::ios_base::ate); 
    std::cout << fs2.tellp() << std::endl; 
    fs2.close(); 

    return 0;   
}
```

gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)

g++ file02.cpp

./a.out

12 
0

Why does fs2.tellp() print 0, but not 12?

Answer (score 4):

When you open a file for output with `std::ofstream`, it is truncated unless you set both `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios_base::out`, or you set `std::ios_base::app` in the mode parameter.

The mode parameter passed to the constructors of `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` is forwarded to `std::filebuf::open` member function. Its value determines how the file is opened according to a mapping to the corresponding behaviour for the mode parameter to the C library function `fopen`. This mapping considers all the flags set other than `std::ios_base::ate`. In summary the mapping is as follows:

```
Flag combination:  in  out trunc app | fopen mode
                        +              "w"
                        +         +    "a"
                                  +    "a"
                        +    +         "w"
                   +                   "r"
                   +    +              "r+"
                   +    +    +         "w+"
                   +    +         +    "a+"
                   +              +    "a+"
```

(C++03 omitted the rows with `app` set but `out` unset; these are now equivalent to the rows with `app` and `out` both set.)

In addition, if `std::ios_base::binary` is set, `b` is appended to the `fopen` mode equivalent.

If the combination of flags passed (ignoring `std::ios_base::ate`) does not match one of these combinations then the open *should* fail.

Note that `fopen` truncates the file for modes `"w"` and `"w+"`.

`std::ios_base::ate` causes the position to be set to the end of the file on opening the file. This will have an effect only when the rest of the mode parameter is such that it doesn't cause the opened file to be truncated and the file already exists and has  non-zero size.

Comment: What about std::ios_base::ate ?

Comment: @Alex: What about it? It doesn't affect whether the output file is truncated; it just says seek to the end of the file on opening. Obviously it only has an effect if the file wasn't truncated on opening.

Comment: ate -> (at end) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening.
Nothing about truncate.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it doesn't affect the truncating behaviour. Note, that if you only supply `ate` instead of `out` the open should fail because you haven't specified one of the valid combinations of mode flags that correspond to a `fopen` mode string in the equivalence table in the standard; you need (at least) `out | ate`, but you probably want something like `"r+"` which is `in | out` and you can optionally add `ate`, too. Just `out | ate` will truncate because it's equivalent to just `"w"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying the `out` flag when opening the file again for writing. Do it this way:

```
std::ofstream fs2(fileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
```